how to establish the connections between controller.py, JavaScript (JS), and XML templates in Odoo 17?
Im trying to create basic attendance form, where changing class division will populate the students in the below table, and next column will be selection for present/absent and submitting.
Controller
im trying to redirect to my template using the controller method
class StudentAttendanceController(http.Controller):
@http.route('/attendance_form', type='http', auth="public", website=True)
def attendance_form(self, **kw):
    return request.render("aspire_student_attendance.attendance_form_template", {'today': fields.Date.today()})

@http.route('/submit_attendance', type='json', auth="user")
def submit_attendance(self, **kw):
    class_division_id = kw.get('class_division_id')
    date = kw.get('date')
    student_attendances = kw.get(
        'student_attendances')  # Expected to be a list of dicts with student_id and attendance_status

    Attendance = request.env['student.attendance']
    AttendanceLine = request.env['student.attendance.line']
    faculty_id = request.env.user.id  # Current user's ID

    attendance_record = Attendance.create({
        'date': date,
        'class_division_id': class_division_id,
        # 'faculty_id': user_name,  # Add the teacher's name to the attendance record
        'faculty_id': faculty_id,  # Link the teacher (current user) to the attendance record
        'attendance_status': 'draft',  # Initial state of the attendance record

    })
    for student_attendance in student_attendances:
        AttendanceLine.create({
            'attendance_id': attendance_record.id,
            'student_id': student_attendance['student_id'],
            'attendance_status': student_attendance['attendance_status'],
        })

    return {'success': True, 'message': 'Attendance successfully recorded'}

@http.route('/get_students', type='json', auth='user')
def get_students(self, **kwargs):
    students = request.env['school.class.division'].browse([2]).student_ids
    student_data = [{'student_id': student.id, 'student_name': student.name} for student in students]
    print('student data', student_data)
    return student_data

main.js
`
odoo.define('aspire_student_attendance.attendance_form', ['web.ajax'], function (require) {
        "use strict";
    
        var ajax = require('web.ajax');
        const core = require('web.core');
        var _t = core._t;
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('select[name="class_division_id"]').on('change', function () {
                const classId = $(this).val();
                if (classId) {
                    this.rpc({route: "/get_students",
                              params: {class_division_id: classId}}).   then(function (response) {
                            const studentList = $('#students_list');
                            studentList.empty();
                            $.each(response, function (index, student) {
                                const studentEntry = $('<div>')
                                    .addClass('student_attendance_input')
                                    .text(student.name)
                                    .data('student-id', student.id);
                                $('<input>', {
                                    type: 'checkbox',
                                    name: `attendance[${student.id}]`,
                                    value: 'present'
                                }).appendTo(studentEntry);
    
                                studentList.append(studentEntry);
                            });
                        }).catch(function (error) {
                            console.error("Error fetching students:", error);
                        });
                } else {
                    $('#students_list').empty();
                }
            });
            $('button[name="submit_attendance"]').on('click', function (e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                const classId = $('select[name="class_division_id"]').val();
                const date = $('input[name="date"]').val();
                const studentAttendances = [];
    
                $('.student_attendance_input input[type="checkbox"]').each(function () {
                    const studentId = $(this).closest('.student_attendance_input').data('student-id');
                    const attendanceStatus = $(this).is(':checked') ? 'present' : 'absent';
                    studentAttendances.push({
                        student_id: studentId,
                        attendance_status: attendanceStatus,
                    });
                });
    
                if (!classId || !date || studentAttendances.length === 0) {
                    alert("Please select a class, enter a date, and mark student attendance.");
                    return;
                }
                ajax.rpc('/submit_attendance', {
                    class_division_id: classId,
                    date: date,
                    student_attendances: studentAttendances,
                }).then(function (result) {
                    if (result.success) {
                        alert(result.message);
                        $('#students_list').empty();
                        $('select[name="class_division_id"]').val('');
                        $('input[name="date"]').val('');
                    }
                }).catch(function (error) {
                    console.error("Error submitting attendance:", error);
                });
            });
        });
    });`

Xml template
  <template id="attendance_form_template" name="Student Attendance Form">
        <t t-call="website.layout">
            <div class="container">
                <h1>Student Attendance</h1>
                <div class="attendance-header">
                    <h2>Status: <span t-esc="attendance_status"/></h2>
                </div>
                <div class="faculty-info">
                    <span>Faculty: <span t-esc="faculty_name"/></span>
                    <span>Date: <input type="date" id="date" name="date" class="form-control" t-att-value="today" readonly="readonly"/></span>
                    <span>Class: <select id="class_select" name="class_division_id" class="form-control" required="required">
                        <t t-foreach="request.env['school.class.division'].sudo().search([])" t-as="class">
                            <option t-att-value="class.id"><t t-esc="class.name"/></option>
                        </t>
                    </select></span>
                </div>
                <table class="table">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Student</th>
                            <th>Selection</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody id="students_list">
                        <!-- Students will be loaded here via AJAX -->
                    </tbody>
                </table>
                <button name="submit_button" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit Attendance</button>
            </div>
        </t>
    </template>

Manifest.py
    {
    'name': 'School Management',
    'version': '17.0.1.0.0',
    'category': 'School Management',
    'summary': """School Management Extended""",
    'author': 'AAAA',
    'company': 'AAAA',
    'website': "",
    'depends': ['base', 'web', 'website'],
    'data': [
        'security/ir.model.access.csv',
        'views/student_attendance_views.xml',
        # 'views/website_menu.xml',
        # 'views/assets.xml',
            'views/student_attendance_form.xml',
        'views/home.xml',
    ],
    'assets': {
        'web.assets_frontend': [
            'aspire_student_attendance/static/src/student_attendance_form/**/*',
        ],
    },
    'installable': True,
    'auto_install': False,
    'application': True,
    'license': 'AGPL-3',
}

i think im totally missing the OWL Part here, it would be much appreciated if you could share knowledge on How the communication/connection is happening between OWL, JS and XML and lastly storing to the database.

Please post the code as a text, not a screenshot.

Could you please track your code steps : by adding multiple logger.info() inside the defs of your controller python code  (using import logging) ....and multiple console.log('....') at the end of each of your js functions...and share the results with us ?

Could you please describe what is working well in your code and what is not  (and provide us the displayed errors with Traceback) ?...

helpful post about OWL: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76845183/using-odoo-v16-owl-component-inside-existing-website-page/76847359#76847359

Hope it will help you:

Is it a back-office (only for odoo users) or front-office Form (portal)?

Your js code is a standard jquery code and has nothing to do with an owl component. Helpful post about OWL: Using Odoo v16 OWL Component inside existing website page

Could you please describe what is working well in your code and what is not (and provide us the displayed errors with Traceback) ?...

Could you please track your code steps : by adding logger.info() inside the defs (attendance_form and submit_attendance) of your controller python code (using import logging) ....and console.log('....') inside each of your js functions (onchange...)...and share the results with us ?


You could follow the good existing example of the official addons/portal module, that does not use any js to submit the form:
portal/views/portal_templates.xml:
<template id="portal_my_details">
        <t t-call="portal.portal_layout">
            <t t-set="additional_title">Contact Details</t>
            <form action="/my/account" method="post">
                <div class="row o_portal_details">
                    <div class="col-lg-8">
                        <div class="row">
                            <t t-call="portal.portal_my_details_fields"/>
                            <input type="hidden" name="redirect" t-att-value="redirect"/>
                        </div>
                        <div class="clearfix">
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary float-end mb32 ">
                                Confirm
                                <span class="fa fa-long-arrow-right" />
                            </button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>
        </t>
    </template>

<template id="portal_my_details_fields">
        <input type="hidden" name="csrf_token" t-att-value="request.csrf_token()"/>
        <div t-if="error_message" class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">
            <div class="col-lg-12">
                <t t-foreach="error_message" t-as="err"><t t-esc="err"/><br /></t>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div t-attf-class="mb-3 #{error.get('name') and 'o_has_error' or ''} col-xl-6">
            <label class="col-form-label" for="name">Name</label>
            <input type="text" name="name" t-attf-class="form-control #{error.get('name') and 'is-invalid' or ''}" t-att-value="name or partner.name" />
        </div>
        <div t-attf-class="mb-3 #{error.get('email') and 'o_has_error' or ''} col-xl-6">
            <label class="col-form-label" for="email">Email</label>
            <input type="email" name="email" t-attf-class="form-control #{error.get('email') and 'is-invalid' or ''}" t-att-value="email or partner.email" />
        </div>

<!--- other input fields (Phone...) removed here ... -->
        <div t-attf-class="mb-3 #{error.get('country_id') and 'o_has_error' or ''} col-xl-6">
            <label class="col-form-label" for="country_id">Country</label>
            <select name="country_id" t-attf-class="form-select #{error.get('country_id') and 'is-invalid' or ''}">
                <option value="">Country...</option>
                <t t-foreach="countries or []" t-as="country">
                    <option t-att-value="country.id" t-att-selected="country.id == int(country_id) if country_id else country.id == partner.country_id.id">
                        <t t-esc="country.name" />
                    </option>
                </t>
            </select>
        </div>
        <div t-attf-class="mb-3 #{error.get('state_id') and 'o_has_error' or ''} col-xl-6">
            <label class="col-form-label label-optional" for="state_id">State / Province</label>
            <select name="state_id" t-attf-class="form-select #{error.get('state_id') and 'is-invalid' or ''}">
                <option value="">select...</option>
                <t t-foreach="states or []" t-as="state">
                    <option t-att-value="state.id" style="display:none;" t-att-data-country_id="state.country_id.id" t-att-selected="state.id == int(state_id) if state_id else state.id == partner.state_id.id">
                        <t t-esc="state.name" />
                    </option>
                </t>
            </select>
        </div>
    </template>

portal/models/portal.py:

class CustomerPortal(Controller):

@route(['/my/account'], type='http', auth='user', website=True)
    def account(self, redirect=None, **post):
        values = self._prepare_portal_layout_values()
        partner = request.env.user.partner_id
        values.update({
            'error': {},
            'error_message': [],
        })

        if post and request.httprequest.method == 'POST':
            error, error_message = self.details_form_validate(post)
            values.update({'error': error, 'error_message': error_message})
            values.update(post)
            if not error:
                values = {key: post[key] for key in self.MANDATORY_BILLING_FIELDS}
                values.update({key: post[key] for key in self.OPTIONAL_BILLING_FIELDS if key in post})
                for field in set(['country_id', 'state_id']) & set(values.keys()):
                    try:
                        values[field] = int(values[field])
                    except:
                        values[field] = False
                values.update({'zip': values.pop('zipcode', '')})
                self.on_account_update(values, partner)
                partner.sudo().write(values)
                if redirect:
                    return request.redirect(redirect)
                return request.redirect('/my/home')

        countries = request.env['res.country'].sudo().search([])
        states = request.env['res.country.state'].sudo().search([])

        values.update({
            'partner': partner,
            'countries': countries,
            'states': states,
            'has_check_vat': hasattr(request.env['res.partner'], 'check_vat'),
            'partner_can_edit_vat': partner.can_edit_vat(),
            'redirect': redirect,
            'page_name': 'my_details',
        })

        response = request.render("portal.portal_my_details", values)
        response.headers['X-Frame-Options'] = 'SAMEORIGIN'
        response.headers['Content-Security-Policy'] = "frame-ancestors 'self'"
        return response

    def _prepare_portal_layout_values(self):
        """Values for /my/* templates rendering,without record counts.
        """
        # get customer sales rep
        sales_user_sudo = request.env['res.users']
        partner_sudo = request.env.user.partner_id
        if partner_sudo.user_id and not partner_sudo.user_id._is_public():
            sales_user_sudo = partner_sudo.user_id

        return {
            'sales_user': sales_user_sudo,
            'page_name': 'home',
        }

####### EX: SUBMIT FORM USING JS
If you really need to submit your form using js, the addons/survey provide a quite full fledged example: in static/src/js/survey_form.js:
    // SUBMIT
    // -------------------------------------------------------------------------

    /**
    * This function will send a json rpc call to the server to
    * - start the survey (if we are on start screen)
    * - submit the answers of the current page
    * Before submitting the answers, they are first validated to avoid latency from the server
    * and allow a fade out/fade in transition of the next question.
    *
    * @param {Array} [options]
    * @param {Integer} [options.previousPageId] navigates to page id
    * @param {Boolean} [options.skipValidation] skips JS validation
    * @param {Boolean} [options.initTime] will force the re-init of the timer after next
    *   screen transition
    * @param {Boolean} [options.isFinish] fades out breadcrumb and timer
    * @private
    */
    _submitForm: function (options) {
        var self = this;
        var params = {};
        if (options.previousPageId) {
            params.previous_page_id = options.previousPageId;
        }
        var route = "/survey/submit";

        if (this.options.isStartScreen) {
            route = "/survey/begin";
            // Hide survey title in 'page_per_question' layout: it takes too much space
            if (this.options.questionsLayout === 'page_per_question') {
                this.$('.o_survey_main_title').fadeOut(400);
            }
        } else {
            var $form = this.$('form');
            var formData = new FormData($form[0]);

            if (!options.skipValidation) {
                // Validation pre submit
                if (!this._validateForm($form, formData)) {
                    return;
                }
            }

            this._prepareSubmitValues(formData, params);
        }

        // prevent user from submitting more times using enter key
        this.preventEnterSubmit = true;

        if (this.options.sessionInProgress) {
            // reset the fadeInOutDelay when attendee is submitting form
            this.fadeInOutDelay = 400;
            // prevent user from clicking on matrix options when form is submitted
            this.readonly = true;
        }

        var submitPromise = self._rpc({
            route: _.str.sprintf('%s/%s/%s', route, self.options.surveyToken, self.options.answerToken),
            params: params,
        });
        this._nextScreen(submitPromise, options);
    },



Front-Office form as portal users
Form Template and the controller is working, i can view the form template with the datas, but after selecting the input i was not able to list the data corresponding to that many2one field. Additionally, clicking the submit button did not result in the creation of the record in the backend.


Could you please put console.log(classId) after const classId   in the 2 functions of your js code ? and share the results

To better replicate your problem, Could you share your model.py file and all other files of your module please ?
